# Cygwin appears to install openssl in a non-standard way (for cmake) on windows 10

Tags: cmake, openssl, cygwin-64

OS: Cygwin64

I use this command in cmake to find openssl:

```
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
```

It fails complaining:

```
-- Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY) (found version "1.1.1d")
```

The assumption appears to be that all of the openssl files
are under some single directory such as this:

```
/usr/local/openssl/bin 
/usr/local/openssl/include
/usr/local/openssl/lib
...
```

But cygwin is installing things more or less as follows:

```
/usr/local/bin/
/usr/local/lib/
/usr/local/include/openssl
```

Anyone have an idea about how to get find_package(OpenSSL) to
recognize the cygwin layout?

Comment: "The assumption appears to be that ..." - Where this assumption comes from? According to the error message, CMake has detected **include directory** for the OpenSSL. Only `crypto` **library** cannot be found. Most likely, the installed version of OpenSSL is *platform-incompatible* with the one, against which you configure your project. You may run `cmake` with additional `--debug-find` parameter, so CMake will print which files it searches during `find_package`, and where it searches them.

Comment: I have no idea why it finds the include files.

Comment: "Most likely, the installed version of OpenSSL is platform-incompatible with the one, against which you configure your project." How can this be? I installed ssl through the cygwin setup program, so I do not understand what it would mean for the installed openssl to be "incompatible"; can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

A co-worker told me to add this flag:

```
-DOPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS=TRUE
```

That seems to solve the problem at the apparent expense of using the static library. But I have no
idea why this flag works.